# How to make a font-icon from PNG image?

Tags: css, svg, fonts, icons

At the moment I am using .png images for my icons. I want to convert them to font-icons and use them instead. What I am doing is converting the images to SVG and then importing them in Icomoon, but all I get are blank fields. What am I doing wrong? Are there any requirements that I am missing?

Comment: Where is you png image???

Comment: If you have a valid svg file it should work (i.e. works for me)..

Comment: @thebjorn I am using http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg, what i fear is that its not actually converting the file, but embedding it. I also used Inkscape. It failed too :(

Comment: @Richa Sorry - http://postimg.org/image/z764d2i7j/
I tryed with a black and white version too.

Comment: @Elleshaar, Here is a complete tutorial for creating icon fonts.http://www.lynda.com/Glyphs-App-tutorials/Creating-Icon-Fonts-Web/157228-2.html

Comment: @Hbirjand thanks i will look at it when i go home

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it is the paths in style.css file you got from Icomoon, correct them and it will be okay.